# Use of preterite progressive vs imperfect progressive

Tags: gramática, verbos

When is the preterite progressive tense used as opposed to the imperfect progressive? For example:

> Estuve comiendo

Rather than

> Estaba comiendo

Isn't the preterite progressive a bit of an oxymoron? The preterite shows a completed action, but progressive tenses imply that the action is still ongoing.

Comment: There is a wealth of posts about _pretérito indefinido vs. pretérito imperfecto_. They are often asked via some sort of questions related to ["estuve vs estaba"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=estuve+estaba). You can use the search field on the top right corner (where it says "Search Q&A") to look for preexisting questions and answers that might be related to what you need to know. A previous answer, even for another question, might answer yours.

Comment: I've checked, and the ones I read don't ask about the progressive forms, just imperfect vs preterite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually rather difficult to construct a context for "estuve comiendo" that makes sense.  I was having trouble coming up with something, so I googled it with quotes.  Here are a couple I came across.  They work, but they sure aren't commonly found!

[Example 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=c-9WAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=%22estuve%20comiendo%22&source=bl&ots=N5SKq1DNne&sig=mqpFCopz82ShwPsjWvWKTBtkU-A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7g46RnfPTAhXDy1QKHca_CnQQ6AEIowEwGQ)

> Aquel éxtasis duró todo el tiempo que yo estuve comiendo. *(That ecstasy lasted the entire time I was eating.)*

(I guess there was something special about that particular meal.)

[Example 2](https://m.vitonica.com/respuestas/sirve-hacer-ejercicio-si-estas-comiendo-comida-chatarra)

> Últimamente anduve estresada y a las corridas y estuve comiendo muy mal, mucha comida chatarra y azúcar. *(Lately I was stressed and always rushing, and I was eating badly, with a lot of fast food and sugar.)*

In both cases, we see that there was a period in which eating occurred, but that period had a clear ending, i.e. it is not going on any longer.

Comment: We also use _estuve comiendo con Juan esta semana_, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`progressive tenses imply that the action is* still ongoing`... *or *was* still ongoing at the moment, in the context of whatever you're talking about.
So you'd say "*Ayer estuve comiendo en un sitio muy bueno*" (the action is finished, nothing more to say about it) or "*Ayer estaba comiendo cuando apareció Pedro*" (the action of you eating was still ongoing when Pedro appeared).